# Change the value of ProgressBar after executing each task in WPF?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I want to change the value of the ProgressBar automatically after I executing a method in my WPF project. Here is how my code looks like,

```
    ChangeValueOfProgressBar()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.progressBar.Value = 0;
        }));
        DoTaskA();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.progressBar.Value = 50;
        }));
        DoTaskB();
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            this.progressBar.Value = 100;
        }));
    }
```

and I expect that the value will change to 50 after I finish DoTaskA() method, then turn out to be 100 when DoTaskB() have been done, too. However, the value doesn't change untill DoTaskB been done. 
How do I achieve my goal?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer! Just reference the site :

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/

and it works perfectly!